# Is there a way to synchronize this?

Tags: ruby

Is there a synchronized exec in ruby? I try the following code and when I open the file I get nothing, and it's probably because exec doesn't finish writing the file.

```
exec "sort data.txt > data.sort"
File.foreach("data.sort") { |line| puts line}
```

Ted

Comment: Are you sure it's because of that, and not because the command fails to execute in the first place? I don't know much about Ruby, but I very much doubt `exec` will not be allowed to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were looking for `system`, not `exec`. However, it's a lot easier than that if you use backticks, which return the output of the command.

```
puts `sort data.txt`
```

If you need to iterate, then you can iterate over the return value directly:

```
sorted = `sort data.txt`
sorted.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

or even:

```
`sort data.txt`.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`exec` replaces the current process with the one you are executing; nothing after the `exec` gets run at all! You probably want `system` instead.